# $f(x) = \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor$ Find $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f(x) = \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor$ Find $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$

I kind of know what floors are but I'm really lost on how to solve this.

$\lim_{x\to0^+}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor$ so as $x$ approaches $n$ from above, $\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor = n^2 - 1$

 So now I have $\lim_{x\to n^+}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor = n^2-1 = -1$

$\lim_{x\to0^-}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor$ so as $x$ approaches $n$ from below, $\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor = n^2 - 2$

 So now I have $\lim_{x\to n^-}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor = n^2-2 = -2$

 If anyone can explain what I did wrong it'd be greatly appreciated. I have a couple other problems that like this so I really need to get this concept down.

Comment: What is $(0-\epsilon)^2 -1$?

Comment: An absolute value cannot be negative. You started drofting apart since then.

Comment: Those aren't absolute values. They're the greatest integer function (floor).

Comment: ._. Forgive me, from this phone I confused them (visually) I am deleting this comments in a while...

Comment: It's no big deal chub :D Daniel.. isn't that just $\epsilon^2 - 1$? I'm clueless

Comment: Yes, it's $\epsilon^2 - 1$. So what is $\lfloor (0-\epsilon)^2-1\rfloor$? (For small $\epsilon$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

(a)$\quad \lfloor x^2-1\rfloor=\lfloor x^2\rfloor -1$.

(b)$\quad$What is $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ when $-1<x<0$ and when $0<x<1\ $?

Comment: $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ is $-1$ and $0$ respectively. OOOOH I get it now. That's the part I was missing. So $\lim_{x\to n^-}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor = n^2-2$ with $n$ being $-1^2$ it would come out to $1 - 2 = -1$ Thank you so much